# How to make sure X number of XHR callbacks have fired and finished before i do something?

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

So i have these 4 requests, each of them have their own callback and can fire in any order they want. but i need that before i execute `mergeData` all the callbacks from the requests have finished successfully.

my problem with the aproach im using right now is that the initial values in the parameters once i call `waitForSync` dont ever refresh (also i dont feel pretty comfortable with this aproach, i feel like im doing it wrong). 
anyone to point me in the right direction?

```
var heroes = requestDataFromAPI('heroes');
var weapons = requestDataFromAPI('weapons');
var races = requestDataFromAPI('races');
var jobs = requestDataFromAPI('jobs');

waitForSync(heroes, weapons, races, jobs);
```

...

```
function waitForSync(heroes, weapons, races, jobs){
  if (heroes && weapons && races && jobs) {
    mergeData(heroes, weapons, races, jobs);
  }
  else {
    setTimeout(waitForSync, '500', heroes, weapons, races, jobs);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at [promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)? You could use [`Q.all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall) instead of doing something like this yourself.

Comment: Depending on the implementation of `requestDataFromAPI` wouldn't a simple counter suffice? ++cnt after your request is done? The used vars in your code seem global anyway, so what's one more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are their types? Are they plain XHR objects? jQuery XHRs? Either way, each of them will evaluate to `true` when coerced to booleans, so the condition will also be `true`.

You can change your code to check [`readystate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and increment a counter, but I would take a different approach and use [Q promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) instead.

You can even easily handle errors this way,

For example (assuming `requestDataFromAPI` returns a jQuery XHR):

```
// First, convert jQuery XHRs to Q promises

var heroesPromise = Q(requestDataFromAPI('heroes'));
var weaponsPromise = Q(requestDataFromAPI('weapons'));
var racesPromise = Q(requestDataFromAPI('races'));
var jobsPromise = Q(requestDataFromAPI('jobs'));

// Now, wait for all of them to finish

Q.all([heroesPromise, weaponsPromise, racesPromise, jobsPromise])
  .spread(function (heroes, weapons, races, jobs) {
    // Do something with results!
    console.log(heroes, weapons, races, jobs);    
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Something bad happened', err);
  })
  .done();
```

If you're not yet familiar with promises, do yourself a favor and **[read up on them](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)**. They're the easiest abstraction for asynchronicity that I'm aware of, and allow to avoid a lot of complexity. You'll be glad you  did it.

The linked article discusses native promises, but until they are available in all browsers, you'll need to resort to libraries like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). Also worth knowing: [don't use jQuery promises, they are bad](http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2013/01/22/javascript-promises-and-why-jquery-implementation-is-broken/) (that's why I wrap them in `Q()` calls).

Comment: Good solution, but might hard to understand by a programmer who have no knowledge about promises or functional programming.

Comment: @Neversay: true, but in 2014 it's harder and harder to stay away from the code having to be asynchronous-by-default. And promises are the easiest abstraction to reason about asynchronicity I've seen yet. I'll add a link with promises intro though, thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much. that article helped me tons!

Comment: @Viktor: Sure, no problem! Once you learn the basics, check out [Q API reference](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference), there are many useful methods there.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your requestDataFromAPI(String) to requestDataFromAPI(String, Function), the second parameter is the callback function.

So you can call the callback function once you finished the requestDataFromAPI.

```
requestDataFromAPI = function(type, callback) {
    ....
    callback();
}
```

And then rewrite your whole script like this:

```
var heroes = false,
weapons = false,
races = false,
jobs = false,
waitForSync= function(){
  if (heroes && weapons && races && jobs) {
    mergeData(heroes, weapons, races, jobs);
  }
};

requestDataFromAPI('heroes', function(){heroes = true; waitForSync();});
requestDataFromAPI('weapons', function(){weapons = true; waitForSync();});
requestDataFromAPI('races', function(){races = true; waitForSync();});
requestDataFromAPI('jobs', function(){jobs = true; waitForSync();});
```